# Batch file to unregister inaccessible VirtualBox

Tags: batch-file, virtualbox

I have a problem with inaccessible VirtualBox machines freezing VirtualBox which then requires reset via Windows Task Manager. These VirtualBox instances are already launched by a .bat file so I wanted to include code in the .bat to unregister inaccessible machines (only) prior to launch. The preference is not to write files to disk, so am trying to do this using a var. I have the following code which will echo any current inaccessible machines:

```
ECHO OFF
SET LOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET var=%%F 
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" list vms`) DO (
ECHO.%var% | FIND /I "inaccessible">Nul && ( ECHO %var% )
)
```

I'm not so sure that this is the right way to use a find within a loop, but in any-case what I want to achieve after locating the inaccessible machine is to use its UUID to unregister it:

```
SET SUBSTRING=%UUID:~18,-1%
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" unregistervm %SUBSTRING% > nul)
```

Help getting the two parts of this puzzle together and working much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you put them together. I can't test it for sure, since I don't have vboxmanage, but you should be able to make this work.

```
@ECHO OFF & SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%F IN ('""C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" list vms | FIND /i "inaccessible""') DO (
    SET SUBSTRING=%%F
    SET SUBSTRING=!SUBSTRING:~18,-1!
    "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" unregistervm !SUBSTRING!
)
```

The tricky part is figuring out how to make Batch interpret the quotes around the path AND the `find` string. In the end, I just wrapped the whole string in quotes, and it worked. (Aside: you normally would have to escape the `|`, but not when the whole thing is wrapped in quotes.)

Also, you don't have to do the substring replacement (and the delayed expansion) if you identify your tokens and delimiters right in `for`, but since I don't know the output of vboxmanage, I can't help you there.

Comment: Sidenote: `SETLOCAL` is one word.